# How to get the return value of a function in multiprocessing code

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

This is my python code. I am trying to get the returned value(aa1) from the print_cube()
Is there a way to get the value of aa1 inside the main(). I have to use multiprocessing to call other functions also.

```
import multiprocessing   
def print_cube(num): 
    aa1 = num * num * num
    return aa1

def main(): 
    # creating processes 
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=print_cube, args=(10, )) 
    p1.start() 

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) when you want to retrieve return values.

```
def print_cube(num):
    aa1 = num * num * num
    return aa1


def main():
    with Pool(5) as p:
        results = p.map(print_cube, range(10, 15))
    print(results)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Queue` from `multiprocessing`, then pass it to `print_cube()` as shown below:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def print_cube(num, q): 
    aa1 = num * num * num
    q.put(aa1)

def main(): 
    queue = Queue()
    p1 = Process(target=print_cube, args=(10, queue)) 
    p1.start() 
    print(queue.get()) # 1000
    
main()
```

This is the result below:

```
1000
```

Be careful, if using `queue` module below with process, the program doesn't work properly:

```py
import queue
queue = queue.Queue()
```

So, just use `Queue` from `multiprocessing` module with process as I used in the code above:

```py
from multiprocessing import Queue
queue = Queue()
```